# Zero Division Error in boolean statement Python

Tags: python

```
print(True or 5 / 0 > 3)
```

This is my code but it returns `True`

Is there a reason why it doesn't return a Zero Division Error?

Comment: Because `True` "shortcircuits" the expression. `or` does only evaluate the right side given the left side has as truthiness `False`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Its because True is always true. The Python interpreter does not evaluate the right side of the or operator in this case, because the outcome of an or expression is always true if one of its operands is true. If you enter`5 / 0 > 3 or True` than you get your devision by zero error